# Software to open titled geo PNG file?

Tags: geolocation, gis, geospatial

I'm trying to extract some a data (a map image) from a PNG file which is tiled somehow. The file itself is only 256x256 pixels (according to 'get info' on the mac) but is is 23MB. It is from an iPad app called Mud Map and it contains a map that I purchased but I've lost the original that I converted to this format. When I view this file (renamed to a .PNG) I see one section of the map - 256x256px.

I'm asking this question on StackOverflow because I want to know more about these tiled images. How does one create a tiled PNG and what is the software that will open and or create these things. I'm interested in what metadata is required too. I'm loving the outdoors and mapping!!

Comment: Are you sure that the 256x256 map image is 23MB (and not an entire cache of tiles)? Map tiles are a common way of serving web maps. You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_web_map

Comment: I know is that this file and it's associated XML (.plist) file is the data behind the the particular map that I'm trying to retrieve. The file itself is 23MB which is the approximate size of the other maps I have and when this file is opened, it is 256x256px so there MUST be more image in there somewhere. I liken it to opening a muli-page TIFF file in Windows Preview vs Photoshop i.e. one shows page one only whereas the other shows each page.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question, is that it cannot be done in manner I have described.

The images in the PNG are not tiled, the the files are just merged together which is no doubt an individual feature of the program as is it does not appear to be any kind of standard.

Answer (score -1):

I have no access to application you mentioned in IPad. Just share some thought about possible situation here.

1)  Map tiles are commonly used in GIS web application such as Google maps and so on. It is used to improve the performance especially when user pan very often. A map displayed typical map window is divided into for instance 4*4 separate calls. So maybe only 4 call will be made when user just pan a little bit instead of get the whole map for the 16 tiles.
The source image for this tiles can be in pre-generated tiles or just one static map.

2) Assemble separate images to one in GIS is called image mosaic function. GIS server can read a collection of images and mosaiced them into one with the overlapping part handle based on a certain rule. And the images are in pre defined grid format which are seamless and no overlapping, then it is called tiled images. We could pre-generated the tiles from one mosaiced image, or we can server it on the fly. Some GIS server/library/application does have the tile server function built in.